# How to build architecture better

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-core, architecture, global-variables

I have an ASP.NET Core application which calls a service from another library. The
service works with an external API, which requires a `sessionId`. We have to call a Login API method to get the `sessionId`. How long this `sessionId` lives and when it can be changed - we don't know. Rule is: `sessionId` can be valid for 1 request, for 10 requests, for 100 requests, can be valid 1 minute, 10 minutes, 1 day... Nobody knows it.

The service has many methods to call similar APIs:

```
public class BillRequest
{
    private readonly HttpClient client;

    public BillRequest()
    {
        client = new HttpClient
        {
            BaseAddress = new Uri("https://myapi.com/api/v2/")
        };
    }

    public async Task<List<Dto1>> CustomerBankAccountListAsync(int start, int count)
    {
        List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> nvc = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
        {
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("sessionId", CURRENT_SESSION_ID)
        };

        var customerStream = await client.PostAsync("List/CustomerBankAccount.json", new FormUrlEncodedContent(nvc));
        var customerString = await customerStream.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        //....
    }

    public async Task<List<Dto2>> Method2(int start, int count)
    {
        List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> nvc = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
        {
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("sessionId", CURRENT_SESSION_ID)
        };

        var customerStream = await client.PostAsync("List/Method2.json", new FormUrlEncodedContent(nvc));
        var customerString = await customerStream.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        //....
    }

    // logic to get SessionId here
    public async Task LoginAsync()
    {

    }
```

How to implement to save this `sessionId` inside service?

There are many options to implement:

1. Call `Login` method every time before calling a method. Easy to implement, but bad approach, because we have many unnecessary requests then and use the `sessionId` only once
2. Save the `sessionId` on web application level and try to catch exception, when any method gets an 'invalid sessionId' back, and then call `Login` method, which will return a new `sessionId`. In this case we have to pass `sessionId` to constructor of `BillRequest` class. It works, but I don't like to move responsibility of service to other, because it's internal responsibility of service how to work with API.
3. Save `sessionId` inside the service itself and recall `Login` method inside service, when old `sessionId` is considered invalid, rewrite it by new etc. But how to save it as "static" in memory? I don't want to save it to any external places (file system, cloud etc), but I can't save to variable of class too, because object of class can be recreated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest certain mental shift here towards functional programming.

Think of `sessionID` as of a **stream** of independet values rather than a single object. Then your problem can be redefined in a following (semantically equivalent) way: given a typed stream (`string` in your case), how to **observe** its flow and **react** on incomming changes, which your source code does not control?

Well, there is an answer, proven by an Enterprise™: [reactive extensions](https://github.com/dotnet/reactive).

Techinically such a shift impliest that you're dealing with an `IObservable<string>` inside of your controller, which either can be injected via the standard .NET Core DI approach, or simply defined by the constructor. That's quite flexible, since `rX` gives your fully testable, unbelivable powerful toolset to deal with taks of this kind; `rX` is also compatible with native `Task` and hence, `async/await` feature. Nice fact is that it is really easy to inject required behavior from an outerworld and decorate exising observable with a more appropriate one: so, you're safe: once 3rd party's service logic changes, you can adopt your codebase almost instantly and painlessly.

What is gonna be inside that `IObservable<string>`? Well, I can't say, since you did not give enough information. It might be an [interval](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/interval.html) asking remote server whether current `sessionID` is still valid and in case not - runs relogin procedure and notifies it's subscrivers about new value; it might be a [timer](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/timer.html) responsible for compile-time known rule of expiration, it might be as sophisticated logic as you need: `rX` is flexible enough not to limit you on what can be achieved with it as long as you deal with (possible infinite) streams.

As a consequence, it means that you don't need any global value. Just subscribe to a stream of session ids and take latest - the one which is currently valid, do the job and dispose your subscription. It **is not** expensive and won't hit performance; neither would mess up concurency. Wrap `rX` into `Task` and `await` it, if you'd like to stick to a common .NET fashion.

P.S. 99% of what you would need to deliver an implementation is already there; you just need to combine it.

Comment: but I don't know interval. It's no matter, `sessionId` can be changed by internal server reasons, so, it can be active 1 second or 1 week! And I don't want to do additional requests for validating `sessionId`, it's enough to call for getting new, if any request was failed with old `sessionId`. PS. I implemented it by static variable, but your idea with observing is pretty interesting in any case

Comment: @OlegSh, well, your solution seems to be oversimplistic; anyway, keep in mind that there are 100+ different operators like interval and timer, that can be composed together, which you can apply to your problem in future.